# Compare 2 lists and reduce quantities of resulting list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have 2 lists

grpoList

[image]

I have a second named assembly

[image]

I have the following code

```
grpoList = grpoList.Where(c => assembly.Exists(cr => cr.ItemCode == c.ItemCode)).ToList();
```

This returns

[image]

How do I amend the code such that the line of DocEntry 393 on the results has a quantity of 2 instead of 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to perform a Join between the list and select the required fields out of it like

```
var data = grpoList.Join(assembly,
                                x => x.ItemCode,
                                y => y.ItemNo,
                                (x, y) => new 
                                 { 
                                   DocEntry = x.DocEntry, 
                                   LineNum = x.LineNum,
                                   CarCode = x.CarCode, 
                                   ItemCode = x.ItemCode,
                                   OpenQty = y.OpenQty,
                                   DocDate = x.DocDate
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `OpenQty = x.OpenQty - y.OpenQty, since this looks more like a shopping cart?

Comment: @MartinBackasch am not sure since that's not mentioned in post and moreover it's not evident from the posted resultant data OP want. Will leave it OP to decide if that's happens to be the case.

Comment: That's true. It was just a thought, which comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

we can use linq joins to create the custom outputs:

```
var query = from c in grpoList
            join cr in assembly
                 on c.ItemCode equals cr.ItemCode
            select new
            {
                c.DocEntry,
                c.LineNum,
                c.CarCode, 
                c.ItemCode,
                OpenQty = c.OpenQty - cr.OpenQty,
                c.DocDate
            };
```

Keeping name c and cr same as your question so that you can understand it easily.